# Does set theory always deal with pure set?

Tags: set-theory

My elementary set theory book introduce a one of four rules which consist of axiom of cardinality that 
A ~ {1, 2, 3, ..., K} is equal to card(A) = k, tilde symbol '~' denotes one-to-one correspondence.

Is each element of the set {1, 2, 3, ..., k}(e.g. 1, 2, 3, ..., k) 
actually set? I understand set theory doesn't deal with urelements. These 1, 2, 3, ... help me understand intuitively?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: You can trim your post down to one question using the edit function, and then post the others as separate questions. Please don't forget to search first for each question whether it has already been answered elsewhere on this site.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks, I edit my post, I'll remember what you said.

Comment: What "elementary set theory book" are you studying?  It seems your quotation from the book is a little garbled.  I would guess that ~ here has the sense of "these two sets have a bijection" that defines *cardinal equivalence*.  But perhaps you can clear up the meaning the tilde symbol for us.

Comment: @hardmath My book defines X~Y as there exists one-to-one correspondence f : X → Y. And explicitly my quotation is one of the four rules which consist of axiom of cardinality. It's my fault. This is in 'Set Theory - An Intuitive Approach by Shwu - Yeng T.Lin'. I has its translated version with original form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, every element is a set (and usually we start from zero). $0=\emptyset$ is the empty set. $1=\{0\}=\{\emptyset\}$ is the set whose only element is the empty set. $2=\{0,1\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is the set whose two elements are the empty set and the set whose only element is the empty set. $3=\{0,1,2\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\},$ and so on....

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, ZFC does not have urelements, therefore the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$ and so on need to be represented as sets.

There are in principle many ways to do this, but there is one way that is pretty standard (because it allows a very useful extension to infinite numbers, the so-called ordinals): Each number $n\in\mathbb N_0$ is given by $\{k\in\mathbb N_0|k<n\}$.

Here $\mathbb N_0$ is the set of natural numbers including $0$ (using this notation because somethimes $\mathbb N$ is defined not to have $0$; $\mathbb N_0$ is unambiguous in that regard).

So you get:

- $0 = \{k\in\mathbb N_0|k<0\} = \emptyset$.
- $1 = \{k\in\mathbb N_0|k<1\} = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}$.
- $2 = \{0,1\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

and so on.

Besides the extensibility to ordinals, it also has the advantage that each set has the cardinality of the number it represents. So instead of saying that $A\sim\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ you can just say $A\sim n$.

<sub>Note: Strictly speaking, it is not true that set theory does not deal with urelements; while ZFC doesn't, there are other set theories that do have urelements. However *usually* the term “set theory” is used to refer to ZFC, where urelements indeed don't exist.</sub>